# Android: keep timer running between activities

Tags: java, android, timer, android-activity, adk

I have a timer class that is called when a button is pressed and it begins to countdown and display the remaining time as the button text, but when i leave the activity and return they have stopped and disappear. I know why they stop as part of the android life cycle,and i don't simply want to save the times of them and restart them the when i enter the activity again (like most of the solutions on the internet have). i need to timers to keep running when the activity is not the current one as to be accurate to the length of real time the timer represents. is this possible? any help is appreciated.

timer class that works and need to keep running

```
public class CustTimer {
int length;
Button button;

public CustTimer() {

}

public CustTimer(int length, Button button) {
    this.length = length;
    this.button = button;


}




public void Count() {

    new CountDownTimer(length, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            String min = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/60000 ); 

            long re = millisUntilFinished%60000;
            String secs = String.valueOf(re/1000); 

            button.setText(min + ":" + secs);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            button.setText("done");
        }

    }.start();

}
}
```

code that calls the timer class, in the onCreate() function in the activity.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        buts[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CustTimer t1 = new CustTimer(times[j], buts[j]);
                timers[j] = t1;
                t1.Count();


            }
        });
    }
```

times is the array of timer lengths in millis. buts is any array containing the buttons on the screen for easy access. timers is an array of the timer objects created for each button.

Comment: `i don't simply want to save the times of them and restart them the when i enter the activity again` I find this would be the best way, though, as it is the only way to keep the timer even if the application is completely destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

1. static Timer in your first activity or in your application class. Then you call static getTimer() method. Make it run in another thread (not UI).

   1a. define listener interface in your timer extended class and add activities as listeners to the timer instance. In this case you can make timer a singleton and create it only once in the first activity.
2. make a service with timer. I have a similar task in my app and my timer runs in service successfully updating the view and notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can  store in shared prefs or pass for activity to activity a start time value initialized in your first activity, and use that time as a basis for creating timers in your activities.

Answer (score 0):

make your timer class as static. It may solve your problem.